# How do I create a regular expression to match a word of specific pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

We are looking to match a registration number of specific pattern and length  For example the expression should match (three alphabet - 3 digit)
**aaa-080**
**ccs-124**
**kfz-213**
and reject 
**knv-2213**
**asdf-122**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[a-zA-Z]` for alphabet, use `\\d` for digit, and `{3}` for occurrence:

```
System.out.println("xxx-123".matches("^[a-zA-Z]{3}\\-\\d{3}$")); // true
```

Comment: thank you very much. it works :)
i use "[a-zA-Z]{3}+-+[0-9]{3}"

Comment: @safwan The expression you're using will also match `abc-----123`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}\-\d{3}$


String regex = "^[a-zA-Z]{3}\\-\\d{3}$";
System.out.println("aaa-080".matches(regex));//true
System.out.println("aaa-0800".matches(regex));//false
System.out.println("aaaa-080".matches(regex));//false
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
//Your Input "aaa-1234 ccs-123 kfz-123"
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("aaa-[0-9]{3} ccs-[0-9]{3} kfz-[0-9]{3}", "aaa-1234 ccs-123 kfz-123"));

//Your Input "aaa-123 ccs-123 kfz-123"
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("aaa-[0-9]{3} ccs-[0-9]{3} kfz-[0-9]{3}", "aaa-123 ccs-123 kfz-123"));

//Reject
boolean right=Pattern.matches("aaa-[0-9]{3} ccs-[0-9]{3} kfz-[0-9]{3}", "knv-2213 asdf-122");
if(right)
{
    System.out.println("Pattern Match");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Pattern Invalid");
}
```

Output :

```
false
true
Pattern Invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this pattren:**

```
^[\w]{3}[-][\d]{3}$
```

`^` : start

`[\w]{3}` : 3 alphabetical characters (small and capital letters), If you want to match only small characters `[a-z]{3}`, to become the pattern `^[a-z]{3}[-][\d]{3}$`

`[-]` :  -

`[\d]{3}$` : ends with 3 numbers

You can test it [online](https://regex101.com/)

[image]